# Angularjs web api rewrite url rule, for url with parameter

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, web-config, page-refresh

I am working on SPA application using Angularjs and .Net's web api. It all seems to work, in ability to refresh my pages I have added  rules to my web.config file as follows and they all work except one, when I refresh detail page that has a parmeter, something like this `http://domain/traveldetail/135`. Please advise how should I approach this:

Web.config's rewrite section:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="TravelList" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^travellist" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="TravelDetail" stopProcessing="true">  <!--NOT WORKING-->
          <match url="^traveldetail/:travelId" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AdvancedSearch" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^advancedsearch" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="CreditCardMatcher" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^creditcardmatcher" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ApprovalGroups" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^approvalgroups" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Help" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^help" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you figure anything out?

Comment: I was transferred to another project, so I had no chance to research any farther

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the `:travelId` in `url="^traveldetail/:travelId"` is the parameter notation for AngularJS and not a valid regular expression.

Change it for something like this: `url="^traveldetail/(.+)"`, and it should work.